# How to implement concurrent/parallel calls to multiple external rest APIs using expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to fetch car travel package from multiple suppliers using their APIs and merge them in controller and send it to client.

what i am facing as problem is in handling errors, I have two different suppliers APIs at the moments.

1. talixo & 2. Iway

I am calling both APIs at a time, i am getting results and i am able to send it to client. but problem is if any of them giving me error, then i don't get result at all.

i just want it to work like if one is failed or bad result due to some parameter not servicable or anything, other API's result should work.

here is what i have done so far.

this is my cars.controller.js in controllers

```
    const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const pick = require('../utils/pick');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const axios = require('axios');
const { talixoService } = require('../services');
const { iwayService } = require('../services');

const searchCars = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const { data: talixoData } = await talixoService.findTalixoCars(req.body);
        const { data: iwayData } = await iwayService.findiWayCars(req.body);
        
        const taxiresults = [];

        if (talixoData.taxis.length) {
            talixoData.taxis.forEach(function (item) {
                arrcars = {};
                arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                taxiresults.push(arrcars);
            });
        }
        
        if (talixoData.limousines.length){
            talixoData.limousines.forEach(function (item) {
                arrcars = {};
                arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                taxiresults.push(arrcars);
            });
        }
        

       if (iwayData.result.length) {
            iwayData.result.forEach(function (item) {
                var imgsrc = "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/";
                arrcars = {};
                arrcars["carname"] = item.car_class.models[0];
                arrcars["originprice"] = item.price;
                arrcars["packageId"] = item.price_uid;
                arrcars["image"] = imgsrc + item.car_class.photo;
                arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.allowable_time;
                arrcars["maxluggage"] = "";
                arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.car_class.capacity;
                arrcars["discountprice"] = item.price;
                arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                arrcars["vendor"] = "iway Transfers";
                arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                taxiresults.push(arrcars);
            });
        }
        
        res.json(taxiresults)

    }
    catch (err) {

        res.send(err)

    }

});



module.exports = {
    searchCars
}
```

this is my talixo.service.js in services layer

```
    const catchAsync = require('../../../utils/catchAsync');
const axios = require('axios');
const Talixoapi = '****************'


const findTalixoCars = async (carsBody) => {
    //
    const talixoheaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Partner': Talixoapi
    }

    const payload = {
        "start_point": carsBody.start_point,
        "end_point": carsBody.end_point,
        "start_time_date": carsBody.start_time_date,
        "start_time_time": carsBody.start_time_time,
        "passengers": carsBody.passengers,
        "sport_luggage": carsBody.sport_luggage,
        "animals": carsBody.animals,
        "luggage": carsBody.luggage
    }

    const taxiresults = await axios.post(`https://talixo.com/en/mapi/v3/vehicles/booking_query/`, payload, {
        headers: talixoheaders
    })

    //console.log (taxiresults);
    return taxiresults

};



module.exports = {
    findTalixoCars
}
```

and this is iway.service.js

```
    const catchAsync = require('../../../utils/catchAsync');
const axios = require('axios');


const findiWayCars = async (carsBody) => {

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer **************'
    }

    const taxiresults = await axios.get(`https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v3/prices?user_id=1863&lang=en&currency=USD&start_place_point=24.9178231%2C55.0111167&finish_place_point=25.259478%2C55.3229291`, {
        headers: headers
    })

    return taxiresults

};

module.exports = {
    findiWayCars
}
```

i am able to produce results like this when i send json body in post method.

i send this in post request

```
    {
    "start_point": "SVO Airport",
    "end_point": "Ozerkovskaya Naberezhnaya, 26, Moscow, Russia",
    "start_time_date": "2021-11-24",
    "start_time_time": "14:55",
    "passengers": 1,
    "sport_luggage": 0,
    "animals": 0,
    "luggage": 2
}
```

and i get this as a result like i wanted.

```
    [
    {
        "carname": "Toyota Prius",
        "originprice": 34.65,
        "packageId": "34427",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/economy.png",
        "freewaittime": 45,
        "maxluggage": 3,
        "maxpassengers": 3,
        "discountprice": 34.65,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "VW T5",
        "originprice": 46.75,
        "packageId": "34429",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/economy_van.png",
        "freewaittime": 45,
        "maxluggage": 7,
        "maxpassengers": 6,
        "discountprice": 46.75,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Mercedes-Benz Sprinter",
        "originprice": 120.2,
        "packageId": "34430",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/minibus.png",
        "freewaittime": 45,
        "maxluggage": 15,
        "maxpassengers": 15,
        "discountprice": 120.2,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Mercedes-Benz E-Class",
        "originprice": 46.75,
        "packageId": "34431",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/business.png",
        "freewaittime": 60,
        "maxluggage": 3,
        "maxpassengers": 3,
        "discountprice": 46.75,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Mercedes-Benz V-Class",
        "originprice": 99,
        "packageId": "34433",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/business_van.png",
        "freewaittime": 60,
        "maxluggage": 7,
        "maxpassengers": 6,
        "discountprice": 99,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Mercedes-Benz S-Class",
        "originprice": 121,
        "packageId": "34434",
        "image": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/first.png",
        "freewaittime": 90,
        "maxluggage": 3,
        "maxpassengers": 3,
        "discountprice": 121,
        "vehicletype": "limo",
        "vendor": "Talixo",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Volkswagen Jetta",
        "originprice": 66.45,
        "packageId": "aaecf387-dca1-4070-94e9-03f3a40c394b",
        "image": "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/6b6xw3z2m1.png",
        "freewaittime": 6,
        "maxluggage": "",
        "maxpassengers": 3,
        "discountprice": 66.45,
        "vendor": "iway Transfers",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    },
    {
        "carname": "Toyota Previa",
        "originprice": 116.28,
        "packageId": "89d1ea54-38a5-40cf-84fd-ba705e6f31ca",
        "image": "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/36eg82060g.png",
        "freewaittime": 12,
        "maxluggage": "",
        "maxpassengers": 5,
        "discountprice": 116.28,
        "vendor": "iway Transfers",
        "vehicleremarks": "Or Similar"
    }
]
```

But if i send some wrong data in iway or talixo or just pass the wrong authorisation code. then i will get this as response.

```
    {"message":"Request failed with status code 401","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 401\n at
createError (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n at
settle (/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)\n at
IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd
(/Users/rishavkumar/Documents/GitHub/TTCBackendAPI/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)\n at
IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\n at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)\n at
processTicksAndRejections
(internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)","config":{"url":"https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v3/prices?user_id=1863&lang=en&currency=USD&start_place_point=24.9178231%2C55.0111167&finish_place_point=25.259478%2C55.3229291","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MjM1MzI0MzEsImV4cCI6MTY1NTA2ODQzMSwidXNlciI6eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxODYzLCJsb2dpbiI6bnVsbCwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiIxODMwVm9sZGVtb3J0In19.FF_rY3sH72HkVS7Kfr4fWMUPR1qXFWNKSXvb4bxcVB","User-Agent":"axios/0.21.4"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false}}}
```

I just want to avoid such error because of one supplier's end error, because other supplier giving me result, i want to show them to client and i want to store these error in somewhere error log or database, so i can see something causing error and can resolve.

how to achieve that?

update answer after follwing suggestion.

```
const searchCars = function (req, res) {
  
    const talixoData = talixoService.findTalixoCars(req.body) //call talixo api in services
    const iwayData = iwayService.findiWayCars(req.body) //call iwaytransfers api in services

    return Promise.allSettled([talixoData, iwayData]).then(([restalixo, resiway]) => {
        const taxiresults = [];
        if (restalixo.status === "fulfilled") {
            console.log(restalixo.value.data);
            if (restalixo.value.data.taxis.length) {
                restalixo.value.data.taxis.forEach(function (item) {
                    arrcars = {};
                    arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                    arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                    arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                    arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                    arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                    arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                    arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                    arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                    arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                    arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                    arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                    taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                });
            }
            if (restalixo.value.data.limousines.length) {
                restalixo.value.data.limousines.forEach(function (item) {
                    arrcars = {};
                    arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
                    arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
                    arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
                    arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
                    arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.included_waiting_time;
                    arrcars["maxluggage"] = item.luggage;
                    arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.seats;
                    arrcars["discountprice"] = item.discount_price;
                    arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                    arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
                    arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                    taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                });
            }
        }

        //iwaytransfers supplier data
        if (resiway.status === "fulfilled") {
            console.log(resiway.value.data);
            if (resiway.value.data.result.length) {
                resiway.value.data.result.forEach(function (item) {
                    var imgsrc = "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/";
                    arrcars = {};
                    arrcars["carname"] = item.car_class.models[0];
                    arrcars["originprice"] = item.price;
                    arrcars["packageId"] = item.price_uid;
                    arrcars["image"] = imgsrc + item.car_class.photo;
                    arrcars["freewaittime"] = item.allowable_time;
                    arrcars["maxluggage"] = "";
                    arrcars["maxpassengers"] = item.car_class.capacity;
                    arrcars["discountprice"] = item.price;
                    arrcars["vehicletype"] = item.vehicle_type;
                    arrcars["vendor"] = "iway Transfers";
                    arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
                    taxiresults.push(arrcars);
                });
            }
        }
        if (taxiresults.length) {
            //Ascending Order Price Sort
            sortedresult = taxiresults.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.discountprice - b.discountprice;
            });
            //send result to client
            res.send(sortedresult, httpStatus.OK)
        }else{
            res.send("No Cars Found this Location", httpStatus.OK)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could promisfy your api calls and then use `Promise.allSettled()` to return results even if they error

```js
const apicallone = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //api call 1. resolve or reject based on success/error
    });
};

const apicalltwo = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //api call 1. resolve or reject based on success/error
    });
};

router.post('/yourendpoint', (req, res) => {
    Promise.allSettled([apicallone, apicalltwo]).then(results => {
        return res.status(200).json(results);
        // results is an array of objects that will contain either the data returned by the promise resolving or a rejection message. 
        // results.forEach(result => console.log(result.status)) will show that the promise is fulfilled or rejected. 
        // the order of the results should be the same as they are in the array passed into Promise.allSettled 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for response ! i am trying to read and understand this, but in my case, how i will implement this in my controller. can't we use promise.allsettled in controller rather than router, also where i will create our own json array response by pushing foreach to a json array from every successful api responses.

Comment: i finally followed you and made it work.

Comment: do you think, in anyway, i can optimise above code.